# Animate two elements from single hover event

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to hover over one element and have it animate two elements from that one hover event, but I'm having an issue with my jQuery code.

(I'm theming a Drupal view but I posted this on the regular Stack Exchange rather than Drupal answers because I thought the issue was more likely to be with my jQuery coding than Drupal)

The background to how the page is set up:

- Two images are CSS positioned on top of each other, a "teaser" image and a "reveal" image.
- The title is also CSS positioned on top of the images, with a higher z-index so that it always appears on top.
- The title and both images all reside within an outer div container with the class *.views-row*

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- When I hover over the "teaser" image, it animates so that it fades away to opacity=0, revealing the "reveal" image.
- Based on the same hover event over the teaser image, I want to change the CSS for the background of the "title" div.

What's currently happening:

- The image opacity change is happening as intended.
- However, the background is not changing on the "title" div

Script as follows:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $(".views-row");
    $container.find(".views-field-field-teaser-image").hover(
      function() {
          $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0", "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"},1000);
          $container.find(".views-field-title").stop().animate({"background": "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"},400)}
      function() {
          $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1", "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"},1000)
          $container.find(".views-field-title").stop().animate({"background": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"},400)}
      );
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Issues was as follows:

- jQuery `animate()` doesn't support CSS shorthand (e.g. `background:`)
- Changing background color is only supported with the jQuery Color plugin.

Additionally:

- As it's a Drupal view with multiple elements using the same class name for each *View Row*, I needed to do a bit of DOM traversal too.

Fixed code as follows:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $container = $(".views-row");
  $container.find(".views-field-field-teaser-image").hover(
    function() {$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0", "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"},1000),
                $(this).closest(".views-row").find(".views-field-title").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"},1000)},
    function() {$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1", "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"},1000),
                $(this).closest(".views-row").find(".views-field-title").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"},1000)}
    );
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things, you are missing a comma between the 2 in and out handler functions in the hover and the attribute to animate background color is "backgroundColor", not "background". I also don't think you need to use the find() and can access the elements directly using $().

Below is code tested on FF & Chrome that does what you have described, assuming the area of the title div is smaller than the area of the images so that a hover can be detected on the image area not covered by the title div.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style>
            .views-field-title {position:absolute; top:0; z-index: 10; width:100px; height:20px; color:blue; background-color:yellow;}
            .views-field-field-teaser-image {position:absolute; top:0; z-index: 5}
            .views-field-field-reveal-image {position:absolute; top:0; z-index: 1}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="views-row">
        <div class="views-field-title">TITLE</div>
        <img class="views-field-field-teaser-image" src="img/teaser.png">
        <img class="views-field-field-reveal-image" src="img/reveal.png">
        </div>

        <script>

        (function ($) {
          $(document).ready(function(){
            var $container = $(".views-row");
            $container.find(".views-field-field-teaser-image").hover(
              function() {
                  $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0", "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"},1000);
                  $(".views-field-title").stop().animate({"backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"},400)
              }, function() {
                 $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1", "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"},1000);
                 $(".views-field-title").stop().animate({"backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"},400);
              }
              );
          });
        })(jQuery);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, yes, if there are multiple items, you will need to do some more specific targeting rather than $("views-field-title")